# Azure VM unable to connect to CacheFly CDN

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have Windows 10 Azure VM and trying to play videos from CDN (vid.pluralsight.com), but it cannot connect to this cdn. Tried tracert to this cdn but it is timing out. this cdn is on http://www.cachefly.com/.

Anybody knows where to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is disabled on Azure VM's, so your tracert calls will timeout/fail (even with http/UDP supported packages). That being said, I would reach over to PluralSight support, it would be logic on their end in their CDN configurations denying access to certain IP's or ranges, or without proper auth tokens. They likely can assist you further. The issue does not appear to be with the CacheFly CDN because other CacheFly CDN enabled content is served appropriately on the Azure VMs I've tried (both Windows/ Linux). If you have a CacheFly account you should be able to pre-warm a few cache locations and pull those with url filters, etc. and see that you can expire content, get geo-cached items, etc.